# umd_camera process dies

Tags: camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

My process of umd_camera dies after executing roslaunch uvc_camera camera_node.launch

The log file is like below:

```
[roscpp_internal] [2011-03-03 16:25:48,161] [thread 0xb6b41920]: [DEBUG] UDPROS server listening on port [52547]
[roscpp_internal] [2011-03-03 16:25:48,170] [thread 0xb6b41920]: [DEBUG] Started node [/uvc_camera], pid [5366], bound on [rootx-laptop], xmlrpc port [59715], tcpros port [42953], logging to [/home/rootx/.ros/log/cb97488a-4584-11e0-85fd-f04da28296e0/uvc_camera-2.log], using [real] time
[roscpp_internal] [2011-03-03 16:25:48,180] [thread 0xb6b41920]: [DEBUG] XML-RPC call [getParam] returned an error (-1): [Parameter [/uvc_camera/num_worker_threads] is not set]
[roscpp_internal] [2011-03-03 16:25:48,238] [thread 0xb6b40b70]: [DEBUG] Accepted connection on socket [7], new socket [11]
[roscpp_internal] [2011-03-03 16:25:48,238] [thread 0xb6b40b70]: [DEBUG] TCPROS received a connection from [127.0.1.1:33958]
[roscpp_internal] [2011-03-03 16:25:48,238] [thread 0xb6b40b70]: [DEBUG] Connection: Creating TransportSubscriberLink for topic [/rosout] connected to [callerid=[/rosout] address=[TCPROS connection to [127.0.1.1:33958 on socket 11]]]
[ros.camera_info_manager] [2011-03-03 16:25:48,542] [thread 0xb6b41920]: [INFO] camera calibration URL: file:///opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/camera_umd/uvc_camera/example-right.yaml
[ros.camera_info_manager] [2011-03-03 16:25:48,543] [thread 0xb6b41920]: [WARN] [camera] does not match name right_camera in file /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/camera_umd/uvc_camera/example-right.yaml
[roscpp_internal] [2011-03-03 16:25:48,549] [thread 0xb6b41920]: [DEBUG] XML-RPC call [getParam] returned an error (-1): [Parameter [/uvc_camera/skip_frames] is not set]
[roscpp_internal] [2011-03-03 16:25:48,558] [thread 0xb6b41920]: [DEBUG] XML-RPC call [getParam] returned an error (-1): [Parameter [/uvc_camera/frame_id] is not set]
```

When i try to set last two parameters given in the log, it is not working. It is not showing error with next generated log.

Any help on this?

Prasad

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9268/umd_camera-process-dies/) by [Prasad](https://answers.ros.org/users/61/prasad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 79 on 2011-03-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ken](https://answers.ros.org/users/13/ken/) on 2011-03-03**:
I don't see anything in that log that would indicate why the node is dying. Does /dev/video0 exist? Sometimes the kernel module needs to be reloaded. Can you use the camera if you run "guvcview"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Those last two messages just indicate that the parameter server had no values defined for the `~skip_frames` and `~frame_id` parameters. That is normal and should not be a problem. The driver will probably provide appropriate defaults.

Does the driver work if you **do not** provide those parameters?

If it fails, what are the symptoms?

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1